# the data mix in table view, how do I avoid it? swift

Tags: swift, image, tableview, cell

I have some troubles, I have a table view with a custom cell, the cell has a image view, the image is downloaded from internet, when the data loaded the first time everything is fine, but if scroll quickly the screen, the images will mix.
this is my code

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell:FlinkerTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "flinkerCell") as! FlinkerTableViewCell
        cell.imgeCell.image = nil
        let row = indexPath.row
        let flinkerAux: Flinker = flinkers[row]
        if let stringURL = flinkerAux.image{
            if stringURL != "" {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.imgeCell.downloadedFrom(link: stringURL)
                    cell.imgeCell.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                }
                cell.imgeCell.setNeedsDisplay()
                cell.lblTitle.text = flinkerAux.fullName
                cell.lblSubtitle.text = flinkerAux.phone
            }else{
                cell.imgeCell.image = UIImage(named: "user_placeholder")
                cell.lblTitle.text = flinkerAux.fullName
                cell.lblSubtitle.text = flinkerAux.phone
            }
        }else{
            cell.imgeCell.image = UIImage(named: "user_placeholder")
            cell.lblTitle.text = flinkerAux.fullName
            cell.lblSubtitle.text = flinkerAux.phone
        }
        cell.imgeCell.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        cell.imgeCell?.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }
```

I'm using swift 4.2, I tried with DispathQueue load the images, but when the table view has so much images, the problem is back.
how I should do?

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly known issue. I'm sure you can find a lot with google

The easiest option here is to use any library to download images, like AlamofireImage, Nuke, Kingfisher, SDWebImage

[UITableViewCell asynchronously loading images issue - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344892/uitableviewcell-asynchronously-loading-images-issue-swift)